# Can't retrieve download url from firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to retrieve download url so i can pass it down in promise in the function i'm calling.

In the storage image is uploaded but somehow i'm getting error on the line where i console.log - 404 error like it does not exist ( but it does )

```
uploadFile = (file, metadata) => {
    const pathToUpload = this.state.channel.id; 
    const ref = this.props.messagesRef; 
    const filePath = `chat/public/${uuidv4()}.jpg`; // uuid is a function that creates random string

    this.setState({
      uploadState: 'uploading',
      uploadTask: this.state.storageRef.child(filePath).put(file,metadata)
    },
() => {
       this.state.uploadTask.on('state_changed', snap => {
         const percentUploaded = Math.round((snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100)
         this.setState({percentUploaded})
       },
       err => {
         console.error(err)
         this.setState({
           errors: this.state.errors.concat(err),
           uploadState: 'error',
           uploadTask: null
         })
       })  
    },
    () => {
      this.state.uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadUrl => {
        console.log(downloadUrl) // get error
        this.sendFileMessage(downloadUrl, ref, pathToUpload)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
        this.setState({
          errors: this.state.errors.concat(err),
          uploadState: 'error',
          uploadTask: null
        })
      })
    }
    )
  };
```

If you need more code let me know, but on this point where i log error it's where the problem is.

Simply url of posted image in the DB can't be retrieved, i tried with storage rules but there everything looks fine.

EDIT: With state_changed listener state doesn't change - whole time it stays at 'uploading' while image is being stored in storage

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not waiting for the upload to fully complete before requesting the download URL.  This is usually what a 404 means with this sort of code.  You're going to have to use the promise returned by `storageRef.child(filePath).put(file,metadata)` in order to know when the upload is complete, and only then will you be able to call `getDownloadURL()` successfully on its reference.

Comment: I'll edit my code for you to see what i used in between but on that state stayed 'loading' - like it didn't actually upload while it did

Comment: I don't know react well enough to know what your code is actually doing, but I still it's not waiting until the upload is finished before calling getDownloadURL.  This is a common mistake on all platforms that causes a 404.

Comment: yeah i understand what you trying to tell me, just have to find a way to figure it out :)